# Is it possible to get a store web site address from the street address using a map API call (e.g., Bing Maps, Google Maps)?

Tags: google-maps, geolocation, maps, gis, bing-maps

I want to populate the latitude, longitude, and the web site address of a list of stores (hundreds of stores), based on the street address.

I was able to retrieve latitude and longitude from a street address easily using Bing Map service with the url

```
http://dev.virtualearth.net/REST/v1/Locations?query=[streetAddress]&key=[bingServiceKey]
```

My question is if there is a way to retrieve the web site associated with a company that is located in a street address, using any free maps service API.

Comment: [Bing Local Business Search](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/bing-local-business-search/overview?WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5003235)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Going through the Bing Maps developer documentation I don't see any mention of website or URL in the response from the location services.

I also took a look at Azure Maps (a newer Microsoft mapping platform). If you first geocode the address to get its position, then pass that into the fuzzy or nearby search API, there is a good chance a POI result will be returned if there is one close to the address. These often include website URL's if available. Here are some documentation:

https://azure.com/maps
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/maps/search/getsearchaddress
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/maps/search/getsearchfuzzy
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/maps/search/getsearchnearby
https://azuremapscodesamples.azurewebsites.net/

In Google Maps I believe the Find Place API does this as well, however note that it is significantly more expensive than using Azure Maps (13 to 17 times more based on public listed pricing) https://developers.google.com/maps/billing/gmp-billing#find-place